# Where does WordPress default SimplePie save cache data?

Tags: rss, feed, cache, simplepie

Where does WordPress default SimplePie save cache data? I could only find relevant info about cache durations but not the location. SimplePie has a method called `set_cache_location()` but I cannot find it being used in WordPress.

I'm writing a plugin and if a cache folder is available already by default, I'd like to use it rather than creating for my plugin.

Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, the `WP_Feed_Cache` class uses the `WP_Feed_Cache_Transient` class to store the results into a transient.

So, short answer, either in the database or in the Object Cache if you have a persistent object cache stored.

If you need to cache something for a period of time, use a transient.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: Thanks for the info. I looked into the source in feed.php and there are lines `$feed->set_cache_class('WP_Feed_Cache'); $feed->set_file_class('WP_SimplePie_File');` It looks these are the ones setting a transient. I have a custom class which extends SimplePie which WordPress includes. In that case, can I just use these methods and simply pass the words, WP_Feed_Cache and WP_SimplePie_File?

Comment: You should use `set_transient ` described in the link above.

Comment: Do you mean I should use set_transient() separately from SimplePie? Or are you suggesting that I should implement the function into the custom extended class?

Comment: As I test with my custom class extending the default WordPress SimplePie class, in addition to the above methods, `set_cache_class('WP_Feed_Cache')` and `set_file_class('WP_SimplePie_File')`, `set_cache_duration(apply_filters('wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', $cacheduration, $url))` works fine without errors.

Comment: If you're using it in your plugin, you do want to use `set_cache_class()` and `set_file_class()` there, *not* `set_transient`